# MongoDb Aggregate nested documents with $add

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to get sum value from nested documents.

DB document:

```
{
  "_id": 123,
  "products": [
    {
      "productId": 1,
      "charges": [
        {
          "type": "che",
          "amount": 100
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

i wanted to get sum value.
 `sumValue = products.charges.amount+20;` where `"products.productId"` is `1` and `"products.charges.type"` is `"che"`

i tried below query but no hope:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate(
   [
        {"$match":{$and:[{"products.productId": 14117426}, {"products.charges.type":"che"}]},
     { $project: { "_id":0, total: { $add: [ "$products.charges.price", 20 ] } }}

   ]
)
```

please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take a look at [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator which deconstructs an array to output a document for each element of array. Also take a look at [add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) and [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operators.

### I assume your db query should look like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
{$unwind: '$products'}, // Unwind products array
{$match: {'products.productId' : 3}}, // Matching product id 
{$unwind: '$products.charges'}, // Unwind charges
{$match: {'products.charges.type' : 'che'}}, // Matching charge type of che 
{$project: {'with20': {$add: ["$products.charges.amount",  20]}}}, // project total field which is value + 20
{$group: {_id : null,      amount:  { $sum: '$with20' }}}  // total sum
])
```

Comment: is there any way to update the result in db using same query?  like using $Out or $merge aggregator?

Comment: @phani, If you use mongo 4.2 then it is possible, but I assume that this is more convinient for updating database rather then for production usage. see this: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/command/update/index.html#update-command-example-agg

Comment: Thanks @thev0id.  Using $Merge aggregator i think we can't update same collection. And using $set we can't save aggregator result

Answer (score 1):

You can run [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) twice to convert your arrays into scalar value. The outer condition could be applied as [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html), the inner one can be run as [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            _id: 0,
            total: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: { $filter: { input: "$products", cond: [ "$$this.productId", 1 ] } },
                    initialValue: 20,
                    in: {
                        $add: [
                            "$$value",
                            {
                                $reduce: {
                                    input: "$$this.charges",
                                    initialValue: 0,
                                    in: {
                                        $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$$this.type", "che" ] }, "$$this.amount", 0 ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KC4qKfZwPwv)

Comment: Thanks for your response. is there any way to update 'total' value in document using single query?